# Creating and implementing an array from space delimited text: AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

and thank you for your patience. I am an experienced coder using old school methods, and have used the old style of Javascript for many years. I've known about JQuery, and such as that for a while, but have been "too busy" to learn the new things. Well, I am now working on learning those things, and have chosen AngularJS.

I am watching the tutorial videos, and reading the documents and API reference for AngularJS, but the different nomenclature does impede my progress. But I'm trying. For me, using an example of a "real" sort of problem helps me to understand how to leverage the functionality.

In this example, I have an array of Power Ball numbers, and want to be able to paste in the space delimited winning numbers you might copy off of the Power Ball site. This would then parse the input and hi-lite all of the individual numbers. Eventually, perhaps hi-liting any winning combinations in different ways. No, this isn't a product I'm building, but I thought this would cause me to use many different tools in this tool box.

So my questions are:

- I initialized the array in my service (factory) and have shown that I can push to it from my controller. Is this correct?
- Is my current way of doing things (e.g. ng-class usage, etc.) at least feasible, if not correct?
- How could I use space delimited input in the input/text box to do the comparison for the style changes?

Here is an example of my JavaScript code. (note: I'm only pasting in one set of numbers for the array.)

```js
    var lotteryCheckApp = angular.module('lotteryCheckApp', []);
    lotteryCheckApp.factory('PowerBall', function() {
        var PowerBall = {};
    PowerBall.numArray = ["42"];
    PowerBall.myNumbers = [
        {
            First_Number: '03',
            Second_Number: '07',
            Third_Number: '17',
            Fourth_Number: '21',
            Fifth_Number: '42',
            PowerBall: '21'
        }
    ];
    return PowerBall;
});

lotteryCheckApp.controller('PowerBallNumbersCtrl',function($scope,PowerBall) {
    $scope.powerball = PowerBall;
    $scope.winningStyle = true;
    $scope.powerball.numArray.push("21");

    $scope.myCheck = function(searchNum,numVal) {
        // the following code works for a simple input to value check
        if(searchNum == numVal) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

I have a JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Divermarv/VpyxZ/1/

Again, thank you all for your patience and responses.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. This question belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you're getting into angular. Here is how I would solve your problem [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/VpyxZ/2/)

I use ng-change to watch the input values,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input" ng-change="convert()">
```

and feed that to a method that converts the input to an array of values.

```
$scope.convert = function() {
    $scope.hiLite = $scope.input.split(" ");    
}
```

Then your check function checks to see if the value is in the array

```
$scope.myCheck = function(searchNum,numVal) {
    if(searchNum.indexOf(numVal) !== -1) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Is that kind of what you were thinking?

Comment: That seems to work perfectly. I appreciate your feedback, and thank you. When I get my little educational project finished, I'll post it up here just for an FYI for anyone searching.

Comment: @user3058522 Right on. Accept the answer if it works for you. :) Thanks man.